# Read text file display to console then append text file

Tags: c++, file-io, iostream

I have a text file of names. I want to read the text file into a stream, display it to the console. When it is done, it will prompt the user to enter their name. It should then add it to the file.

I can get it to do both of these things separately but not together. 
Here is my code.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
using namespace System;

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
 fstream myfile;
 string line;
 string name;
    myfile.open("Names.txt",ios::out | ios::in | ios_base::app);
    if (myfile.is_open())
    { 
      while( getline(myfile, line) )
      {
          cout << line << endl;
      }
     cout << "Enter your name!\n";
     getline (cin, name);
     myfile << name;
     myfile.close();
 }
 else
 {
     cout << "file was not opened\n";
 }

    return 0;
}
```

If I leave the while loop in there, it writes all the names to the console, but doesn't append the user entered name to the list. If I take out the while loop, I can add a name to the file but then of course I am not getting a list of the names that are already in that file.

My best guess is, I think it might have something to do with the fact that after I loop through the file using getline, The position is at the end of my stream, so when I try to add a name to it, there isn't any room left in the stream?

Comment: That isn't C++: `array<System::String ^> ^args)`?!?

Comment: I'm using visual studio, i selected the project type CLR Console App. It was supplied for me.

Comment: Looks like you need more tags then.

Comment: Pretty new to C++ as my question explains. Will this have an impact on what I'm trying to do with this File IO ?

Comment: I don't *think* it will, but I cannot say for sure.

Comment: The other option was for me to start a Win32 Console Application. That starts with int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]). I understood that even less.

Comment: @BrandonJ: Use "Win32 Console Application" and replace that line with `int main(int argc, char** argv)` for maximum portability.  Visual C++ accepts the portable version just fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your guess is correct.

The last call to `getline()` (the one that failed) set the error flags on your stream, which will fail any further IO attempts, which is why nothing is actually written in your file.

You can reset the [errors flags with](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/clear/) `clear()` after your reading loop :

```
myfile.clear();
```

**Note:**

You should also test for the returned value of your last `getline()` call.

Comment: Thanks so much! It's nice when the fix is something simple.

Answer (score 0):

Just bumped in to this issue and even though there is accepted answer here I think one can use full code that shows how to use canonical C++ file reading loop:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
using namespace System;

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
 fstream myfile;
 string line;
 string name;
    myfile.open("Names.txt",ios::out | ios::in | ios_base::app);
    if (myfile.is_open())
    { 
      while( getline(myfile, line) )
          cout << line << endl;
      if (file_list.eof())
          file_list.clear();  //otherwise we can't do any further I/O
      else if (file_list.bad()) {
          std::cout << "Error occured while reading file";
          return 1;
     }
     cout << "Enter your name!\n";
     getline (cin, name);
     myfile << name;
     myfile.close();
 }
 else
 {
     cout << "file was not opened\n";
 }

    return 0;
}
```